# How can I get Opera speed-dial and password management features in other browsers?

Tags: windows, browser, web

I heavily rely on Opera's speed dial and password management features. Lack of these two features is really stopping me from switching to another web browser such as Chrome or Firefox.

Opera's password management has two unique characteristics which I rely on heavily:

- It saves passwords on all pages, (apparently) despite the page's meta data asking not to save passwords.
- It offers keyboard shortcut and button to automatically fill in username/passwords and all other fields in a login form, then automatically submit the form. (So I'm only one key/click away from logging into a website)

How can I get those functions in other browsers?

Thank you!

Edit: Reason being that I use other web browsers at work and I wish they could have those functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox just introduced the "Speed Dial", but as far as the Password manager I'm not sure. It works well for me and I've never had problems with it.

Chrome also has a "Speed Dial" type thing as well. As for the password manager I have come across sites that will not save the user name and password.